# Python restart program

Tags: python, restart, python-os

I made a program that asks you at the end for a restart.

I `import os` and used `os.execl(sys.executable, sys.executable, * sys.argv)`
but nothing happened, why?

Here's the code:

```
restart = input("\nDo you want to restart the program? [y/n] > ")
if str(restart) == str("y"):
    os.execl(sys.executable, sys.executable, * sys.argv) # Nothing hapens
else:
    print("\nThe program will be closed...")
    sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: This is unusual. Why are you attempting to reinvoke the program from within the program?

Comment: `restart == 'y'`, the `str` is redundant. Also, why not just use a `while`?

Comment: @claudio26 try it: os.execv(sys.executable, ['python'] + sys.argv)

Comment: @Anup yes that solved the problem. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: This looks like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). The correct way to implement this is to restructure the code so you can simply call a function to re-run the program.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
import os
import sys

restart = input("\nDo you want to restart the program? [y/n] > ")

if restart == "y":
    os.execl(sys.executable, os.path.abspath(__file__), *sys.argv) 
else:
    print("\nThe program will be closed...")
    sys.exit(0)
```

> os.execl(path, arg0, arg1, ...)

`sys.executable`: python executeable

`os.path.abspath(__file__)`: the python code file you are running.

`*sys.argv`: remaining argument

It will execute the program again like `python XX.py arg1 arg2`.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe os.execv will work but why not use directly using `os.system('python "filename.py"')` if you have environment and path variable set something like :

```
import os

print("Hello World!")
result=input("\nDo you want to restart the program? [y/n] > ")
if result=='y':
     os.system('python "C:/Users/Desktop/PYTHON BEST/Hackerrank.py"')
else:
     print("\nThe program will be closed...")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
os.execv(sys.executable, ['python'] + sys.argv)
```

solved the problem.

Comment: This code seems to be the most common way to restart a python program. I'm guessing you're being down voted because of the lack of explanation.

Note that, os.execv is not really a good option on Windows. https://bugs.python.org/issue19124

Answer (score 0):

Just import the program you want to restart and run it under the desired condition like this

Title: hello. py

```
import hello 
if (enter generic condition here):
    hello
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

try using;

```py
while True:
    answer = input("\nDo you want to restart the program? [y/n] > ")
    if answer == "n":
        print("\nOk, Bye!")
        break
```

or

```py
retry = True
while retry:
    answer = input("\nDo you want to restart the program? [y/n] > ")
    if answer == "n":
        print("\nOk, Bye!")
        retry = False
```

It is a way that you can easily modify to your liking, and it also means that you can load variables once instead of loading them every time you restart. This is just a way to do it without any libraries. You indent all your code and put it in a while loop, and that while loop determines whether your code restarts or not. To exit it, you put in a break or change a variable. It is easiest because you don't have to understand a new library.