# Windows 10: Can a Python.py program restart itself?

Tags: python, startup, restart, application-restart

I keep finding this and similar codes:

```
import os
import sys
os.execv(sys.argv[0], sys.argv)
```

or

```
os.execv(sys.argv[0], ["python"] + sys.argv)
```

and many others.

However, I'm pretty sure this doesn't work on Windows, as I keep getting the

> OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error

or the interpreter starts but doesn't restart the program.

What to do?

Comment: Did you check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48129942/python-restart-program)?
There is an explanation on how to restart a python program.

Comment: THANKS! This did it:

`os.system('python "C:/Users/Desktop/PYTHON BEST/Program.py"')`